# How does this code work? I don't understand the sequence of logic

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

```
#printing nodes via pre-order
def Pre(self, tree):
    if tree != None:
        print(tree.data)
        self.Pre(tree.left)
        self.Pre(tree.right)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how recursion works?

Comment: not really and watching youtube videos aren't helping with my understanding either...:/

Comment: But are you familiar with how recursion works? </sorry joke>. Essentially this function prints the tree and then splits the tree into `left` and `right` and then calls the same function again for each half. Which then each half is printed and then split into `left` and `right` and passed back into the function which prints each half and splits each half into `left` and `right` and then passes each half back to the same function, which prints what was passed and splits it into `left` and `right` and calls the same function again for each half which... It stops when there is nothing to print.

Answer (score 1):

This is called 'recursion'.

Assume the tree has the following structure where the left branch (`left`) is shown as / and the right branch (`right`) is shown as \

```
        a
      /   \
      b
     / \
    c   d
```

When `Pre(a)` is called, it first checks against `None`, which is false, thus it goes into the `if`.  It prints the data (`.data` above) of the current node, then it calls `self.Pre(a.left)`, which is `self.Pre(b)`. Calling `self.Pre(b)` results in printing `b.data` and the calling of `self.Pre(b.left)` which is `self.Pre(c)` and calling `self.Pre(b.right)`, which is `self.Pre(d)`. This is not done simulatenously but first the left part, then the right part. When both functions have ended, `Pre(a.right)` is called, and since this is nil, the `if` will not be called.

The order of calling is:

- `Pre(a)`
- `Pre(b)`
- `Pre(c)`
- 'Pre(d)
- 'Pre(nil)`(called from`a.right`)

Recursive functions are typically used for nested structures like lists, dictionaries or trees (like in the example above).

Comment: Ohh i finally understand now, thanks everyone!!

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it helped you.